# How to update parent table when a record is added to child table in ASP.NET MVC5 Entity Framework Data Scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I’m writing my first ASP.NET MVC 5 program with CRUD operations built by Entity Framework(EF) Data Scaffolding for work and I have a question on how to update the parent table when a child is added, updated or deleted onto/from child table without creating userID & updateDate on each of the child record.

I have userID & updateDate fields on parent table.  When I do CUD operations (add, update or delete) with child table, I want to update the parent table with userID & updateDate to reflect who/when record was changed.  How can I do this using the EF Data Scaffolding? Since I don’t have too much experience with MVC & EF, if you could show me in code how this is done in my controller, I would appreciate it.  As of now, I’m able to add a new child record with EF Data Scaffolding using model of individual table for specific view.  I did some search and found a way to do this via model binding with multiple tables if they are both in the view model, but I was wondering if there is any other way to use EF Data Scaffolding to update the parent table after successfully doing the add or update to child table.  I also found an article on using SaveChanges(false) & AcceptAllChanges(), which might be useful once I figure out how to update the parent record after I add or update the child record.  I thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "crossWalkID, location, 
  widthOfLeg, legDirection, crosswalkType, qtyBasicOrHatched12, 
  qtyLadderBar16, qtyLadderBar24, cost")] tblStripingQuantity 
  tblStripingQuantity)
{
// Also update UserID & UpdateDate in the tblCrossWalk when 
// tblStrippingQuantity is updated successfully -   Where to do this???
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
db.tblStripingQuantities.Add(tblStripingQuantity); // Add a new child record 
                                                   // to child table
db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Index", "tblCrosswalks", new { id = 
  tblStripingQuantity.crosswalkID });
}
return View(tblStripingQuantity); // ModelState is invalid; return to view
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm on a mission to eradicate the world of the abuses of `Bind`. Don't use it. It's bad for any number of reasons: code duplication, not strongly-typed, maintenance nightmare, etc. Use a view model instead and save a life. `Bind` kills *both* puppies and kittens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on Assil's answer, your ActionResult would look something like this.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "crossWalkID, location, 
  widthOfLeg, legDirection, crosswalkType, qtyBasicOrHatched12, 
  qtyLadderBar16, qtyLadderBar24, cost")] tblStripingQuantity 
  tblStripingQuantity)
{

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
// Add a new child record to child table
db.tblStripingQuantities.Add(tblStripingQuantity);                                                    

//Gets crosswalk parent record and updates UserID and Date
var crossWalk = db.tblCrossWalk.Find(tblStripingQuanity.crossWalkID);
crossWalk.UserID = 1234;
crossWalk.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;

db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Index", "tblCrosswalks", new { id = 
  tblStripingQuantity.crosswalkID });
}
return View(tblStripingQuantity); // ModelState is invalid; return to view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about the BEST way to do that.. Well the best way is to have the CreateDate, UpdateDate fields for the parent as well as the child table. So when you update the child, you update the child.UpdateDate in that very table not in its parent. This is the approach that stood valid, common and followed for long years.
Now if you want to update the parent when any child record is updated, It will not make much sense from managing data perspective, but it is definitely possible by stored procedures or getting the parent record, and set the updated child and then update the parent and EF will know what to do.

Comment: Thank you for your reply; I have clarified my question. I would like to do this without creating userID & updateDate for each child record that I add to child table.

Comment: Then, as @Assil said, actually get the parent record, make the update and save both the parent and the child. Short of that, you'd have to do something like set a trigger on the database, but that's an excellent way to screw up your database.